# Java Serial Reader

Tags: java, serial-port

I found this example using RXTX library. It works fine but I'm trying to understand how it works. Here is the code chunk.

```
public static class SerialReader implements Runnable 
        {
            InputStream in;
            Robot robot;
            int x;
            int y;
            public SerialReader ( InputStream in , Robot robot)
            {
                this.in = in;
                this.robot = robot;
            }

            public void run ()
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len = -1;
                try
                {
                    while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
                    {

                        System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));

                    }
                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }            
            }
        }
```

What I'm trying to understand is the while loop. It looks like it loads the buffer from input stream but since RS-232 send one byte at a time, im confused. What I'm trying to achive is to get the integer representation of the result that is printed out.

Comment: Console result is like this: 0 \n 0 \n 0 \n

Answer (score 0):

What is confusing about it? Even though data is sent one byte at a time, a sequence of bytes can be accumulated in the buffer so you read the whole sequence at once. The value len is how many bytes in sequence have been received. The way you are dealing with the received data though can be changed to reflect your expectations. Try for example replacing this

```
System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));
```

with this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sb.append(String.valueOf(buffer[i]));
}
System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Comment: The confusing part is the byte received count. What decide this length? I was doing somewhat similar to your approach but that example you gave me results with a lot of empty sb. It looks ok when i use the print but it is more obvious with println. I even tried to remove the non-digit bytes but still could not get rid of the nulls.

Comment: The first example gives 0 with a newline even with the print() function. Second example gives the result with a sequence like few blank lines, 48 newline 13 newline 10 and few more newlines